# Parse through XML with Namespace(gml)

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse through my `xml` file and I think it works but when I print the coordinates I only get this on my console: "[ ]".

My code looks like this:

```
tree = ET.parse(url)
root = tree.getroot()
namespaces = {'gml': 'http://www.opengis.net/gml#'}
print(root.findall('gml:coordinates', namespaces))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tree = ET.parse(url)
root = tree.getroot()
for a in root.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}coordinates'):
    print(a.text)
```

This isn't exactly the same code but it does what I wanted so this is the answere to my question.